# double data type value not stored in MySQL using jsp .when i stored value manually it's stored in database

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

It is a rating code..

```
<%-- 
    Document   : ratingdb
    Created on : 24 Jul, 2017, 5:02:11 PM
    Author     : MUHAMMAD SAIM
--%>

<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page language="java"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        try
        {
        int flag=0;
```

we take rating input from user

```
        String review=request.getParameter("star");
        String id=(String)session.getAttribute("id");


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/atm","root","root");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
            int t_user;
            int rating1;
            int t_rating;
        double final_rating=0.0;

        String a=null;
        String b=null;
        String c=null;
        String d=null;
        int flagr=0;
        int user=0;
        rs=st.executeQuery("select * from rate where id='"+id+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            a=rs.getString(1);
            b=rs.getString(2);
            c=rs.getString(3);
            d=rs.getString(4);
```

I check that rating table is equals to null or not..

```
            if(a.equals(null)&&b.equals(null)&& c.equals(null) && d.equals(null))
            {
                flagr=0;



            }
            else
            { 
                flagr++;
                user=1;

               t_user=Integer.parseInt(c);
               rating1=Integer.parseInt(d);
               t_rating=t_user*5;
               final_rating=t_rating/rating1;


            }

        }
```

if it is null then insert query run..otherwise update query run..

```
        if(flagr==0)
        {
        int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into rate(id,number,user,rating) values('"+id+"','1','1','0.0')");
        out.print("Inserted");


        }
```

when I update this rating field through 'final_rating' it doesn't work and when I update this manually it will be updated...what's the problem here..

```
 else
        {
       int i=st.executeUpdate("update rate set number=number+"+review+",user=user+"+user+", rating='"+final_rating+"' where id='"+id+"' ");
        out.println("Updated");
        }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `when i update this rating field through 'final_rating' it does'nt work`, please be more specific than `doesn't work`

Comment: What is type of column 'final_rating' in DB?

Comment: I would strongly suggest using prepared statements

Comment: Cast int to double explicitly  final_rating=(double)t_rating/rating1;